# Antonym for apophenia

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I understand that [**apophenia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apophenia) is the standard term in psychology to describe the tendency to spot patterns where none exist (analogous to a Type I error - false positive).

Is there a standard term to describe the opposite phenomenon? The tendency to miss a pattern where one exists (analogous to a Type II error - false negative).

Comment: Where apophenia is seeing patterns in randomness, there is an unofficial term "randomania" that is seeing randomness in patterns.  It's not used very much though.

Comment: @ArnonWeinberg: Thanks that's useful. Googling I find [some guy on a LinkedIn page](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/twain-apophenia-agenticity-patternicity-randomania-mr-garry-schultz) claiming that "apophenia, agenticity, patternicity, randomania, respectively defined as: tendency to seek patterns in random information, to infuse patterns with meaning, tendency to find meaningful patterns in meaningless noise, attributing to chance what are apparently patterned or related data." Perhaps there are more authoritative references for this claim.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this reference authoritative, but after a bit of research the first article in [this](http://paranthropologyjournal.weebly.com/uploads/7/7/5/3/7753171/paranthropology_vol_3_no_2.pdf) journal (originally published in the Journal of Parapsychology) introduces the term "randomania" as "attributing chance probability to (apparently) related phenomenon." Note that this term is specifically defined in contrast to apophenia.

As an aside, [this](http://blog.synchrosecrets.com/?p=19553) blog post discusses the history of the term apophenia (and potential modern misapplications of its current definition).